# Skip file renaming conversation if #2 or #3 or #(any number) exist in the file name

Tags: c#

Below is my code where I am successfully renaming only the files inside a a folder and also crawls inside every subfolders and renames the entire .png files.

I am trying to add a customization where if the file name already got #1 or #5 or any #(number) then i want the conversation to skip that file and go to next file

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderDlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        //folderDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (folderDlg.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Has different framework dependend implementations 
        // in order to handle unauthorized access to subfolders
        RenameAllPngFiles(folderDlg.SelectedPath);
    }
    private void RenameAllPngFiles(string directoryPath)
    {
        RenameCurrentPng(directoryPath);
        foreach (var item in GetDirectoryInfos(directoryPath))
        {
            RenameCurrentPng(item.FullName);
        }
    }

    private void RenameCurrentPng(string directoryPath)
    {
        int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
        foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png"))
        {
            // The new file name without path
            var newFileName = $"{System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName)}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";
            FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
        }
    }

    private DirectoryInfo[] GetDirectoryInfos(string directoryPath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
        DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories("*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return directories;
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing in your post related to the last three tags - you should remove them

Comment: I suspect part of the solution will be searching for `#` in the filename.

Comment: yes, correct but i am wondering how to integrate in codes

Comment: You can use `IndexOf` method on string or use regex to check if `#` exists in the filename or not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the String.Contains method to check for #.

```
    private void RenameCurrentPng(string directoryPath)
    {
        int fileNameSuffixCounter = 1;
        foreach (string originalFullFileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath, "*.png"))
        {
            string ShortFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFullFileName);
            if (!ShortFileName.Contains("#"))
            { 
            // The new file name without path
            var newFileName = $"{ShortFileName}#{fileNameSuffixCounter++}{System.IO.Path.GetExtension(originalFullFileName)}";
            FileSystem.RenameFile(originalFullFileName, newFileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: may i know, how can i always make the application to open a  specific folder when i click the button?

Comment: Different question. Please ask a new question. This will help future readers. We want to help you but we also want to help those who come after you with the same problem.